# Gradle replaceToken for any string without @@

Tags: gradle, replace, token

Gradle replacing a string in text files:

```
 foo --> bar
```

import org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens

ReplaceTokens requires tokens to be in the format: @token@.

But in ant, a token be anything without @@.

```
from ('/path') {
    filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens:["foo", "bar"])
}
```

It won't work. Replacing line by line is the solution?

```
from ('/path') {
    filter { String line -> line.replaceAll("foo", "bar") }
}
```

Performance issue for a big file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to configure it the same as in Ant, as it is the exact same class. So the following should probably work:

```
from ('/path') {
    filter(ReplaceTokens, beginToken: '', endToken: '', tokens:["foo", "bar"])
}
```

But it doesn't make much different probably than going through the file line by line, so I guess performancewise it doesn't make much difference.

One thing you should remember though. Whenever you use content filtering, set the `filteringCharset`, at least if you potentially have non-ASCII characters in your file, otherwise the system default encoding is used and this can destroy the files content, depending on which system you build.